# Top-rated players in each style

Tags: style

Who are top-rated players (with 2600+ ELO) who are most notable in each of following styles?

```
Aggressive
Positional
Calculating
Technical
Practical
Intuitive
```

Comment: This is hardly any different from your previous question.

Comment: The question is similar (because I'm still looking for answers), but the format is different.

Comment: If you think if there is anything wrong with the question, would you mind enlightening me? Appreciate it. I'm under the impression this is someplace where I can seek help from chess experts. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You should be editing the previous question to make it on topic and a better fit, rather than asking it again in a different way.

Comment: @bhathiya: there is no objective way to say any given player has a certain style, and that list of "styles" looks pretty random.

Comment: There is a section in Yermolinsky's "The Road to Chess Improvement" where he describes how he carefully analyzed games by such famous grandmasters as Tal and Spassky -- and couldn't find significant differences in style between them. He concludes it was mostly journalists putting labels on players to improve their stories.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: Thanks. Could you please help me to make the list complete, at least up to some level? I will try to find that book.

Comment: No, I think it makes no sense to divide players into different "styles". Maybe you can divide them by their approach to opening preparation, but after the opening top players can't really be distinguished by their moves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As addressed in my answer to [What is chess style?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/16790/1108), there is a website called [ChessPersonality.com](http://www.chesspersonality.com/) which gives a list of styles alongside suggested openings and top players you may want to study.

Comment: No problem @Bhathiya. If you feel the answer warrants it, please accept it using the tick mark to the left.